# what is the seekp() and seekg() equivalent for JTextArea in Java?

Tags: java, swing, insert, document, jtextarea

I have the Document of this area. How do I seek to a particular position on this JTextArea's document and write my changes? I want a function somthing like so : Document.addText(int offset, String str); where str is written into the document from position offset.

Comment: Thank you. This question was more of "Think aloud" than a real question. I have ans my own q.

Comment: very good idea to play with model, instead of with view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insertString function does exactly what I was looking for.